# ListView does not validate items from Template

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

When I have a `TextBox` with the following Style, the Validation.HasError property get's triggered and does it's work.

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But when I use a `ListView` with an ItemTemplate, that has an TextBox with the same Style as above, the Validation.HasError property doesn't trigger in XAML and nothing changes.

Summarized XAML code:

```
<!--User Control code-->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DeploymentSettingEntries}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DeploymentItemTemplate}">
</ListView>

<!--App.xaml code for Data Template and Error Style resource-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="DeploymentItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type settings:SettingsEntry}">
    <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
                 Style="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}"
                 Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Parts from ViewModel:

```
public class DeploymentConfigViewModel : ValidatableBindableBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly IValidator<DeploymentConfigViewModel> validator;

    private BindingList<SettingsEntry> deploymentSettingEntries;

    public DeploymentConfigViewModel(IValidator<DeploymentConfigViewModel> validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
        this.validator.ErrorsChanged += (s, e) => OnErrorsChanged(e);
    }

    public bool HasErrors => validator.HasErrors;

    public sealed override void ValidateAllProperties()
    {
        validator.Validate(this);
    }

    public BindingList<SettingsEntry> DeploymentSettingEntries
    {
        get => deploymentSettingEntries;
        set
        {
            deploymentSettingEntries = value;
            deploymentSettingEntries.ListChanged += 
            (sender, args) => ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I debugged the `HasErrors` property in my ViewModel that implements INotifyDataErrorInfo, and in **both cases** it returns True.

I tried calling the Validation.HasError trigger directly on my ListView or putting the Style inside my User control, but none of them worked..
Does someone know why the Validation don't happen at the TextBox but the entire UserControl?

Comment: Why is the style name is different in the DataTemplate? ErrorTextBoxStyle

Comment: That was just an copy and paste mistake - I fixed it now. Unfortunately that has nothing to do with the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work like I imagined, by moving the entire **Validation** part from my `DeploymentConfigViewModel` to my model class `SettingsEntry`.

Therefore my `HasErrors` property and `ValidateAllProperties` method is now in that model class and the property `Value` which is bound to the TextBox looks like this:

```
public string Value
{
    get => value;
    set
    {
        this.value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (validator != null)
        {
            ValidateAllProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

The UserControl code stayed the same. Now each TextBox that fails the Validation is highlighted with a standard red border instead of the entire UserControl.